# Covid-19 - Why are there still a lot of international flights?

Tags: airline-operations

I hope this question is relevent to Aviation. If not, please let me know. Below is a snapshot from Flightradar24. While there are far less flights than usual, there are still a lot of flights en-route.  I thought there were controls put in place last week in several countries. Do these flights have special permission?

[image]

Comment: This may be a better question for the Travel Exchange. There are controls and restriction put in place. That is different than a total prohibition on flights like the type we saw after 9-11.

Comment: The restrictions are on who can still enter a country (pass immigration), not which aircraft can fly where, so this would be a better question for [travel.stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Plus, you can almost treat Europe as one country with the EU. As far as the US, that is not a lot of international flights. It might not be a lot of total flight all together. Considering DFW alone gets 1000 flight cycles every 4 hours of a normal day.

Comment: Thanks Dean. I'll take your comments as an answer, and close the question. David

Comment: Barring foreigners from entering a country is not the same as saying planes are not allowed to fly. A lot of people abroad need to travel home, and a lot of cargo is (and will continue) being moved around

Comment: That said, the number of flights is already dropping drastically, and will continue to do so. https://www.flightradar24.com/data/statistics

Comment: People working and studying in countries with medical infrastructures less prepared for the epidemic are trying to go home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that no one has [shut down any airspaces](http://content.time.com/time/nation/article/0,8599,174912,00.html) yet and that is what stops planes from moving.

While many governments have put travel bans in place for *people* [airplanes often carry other things like mail and cargo](https://science.howstuffworks.com/transport/flight/modern/air-freight1.htm) and it may still be viable and profitable to fly them. There is also the compounded fact that many people are trying to get *home* to quarantine them selves and in the short term there is still *high* demand for flights to move people back to their home countries.

[Airlines are starting](https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/airline-news/2020/03/16/coronavirus-travel-southwest-airlines-cutting-flights-least-20/5063399002/) to cut [flights](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/united-airlines-coronavirus-flights-half-april-may/) due to *reduced demand* and over the next few months you will see a drop in flight traffic but if the airspace is open planes will keep moving.

Comment: Great comments and answers. Many thanks to all. Roger and Out. (I'm old enough to say  that)